# Syncing branches from Github to local repo in VS2019

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-2019

I have a project that I committed to GitHub and then went to the site and manually created three branches there - developers, master, and testers. I can see these branches online.

[image]

When I open this solution from my local repo, these branches don't show up in VS2019.

[image]

I have tried `git clone <url>` from the project folder as well as downloading a zip of the entire project from GitHub to my local folder, but they still don't show the developers and testers branches. What am I missing in Visual Studio to show these branches?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Took a while, but I think I figured it out...go to the 'Synchronization' tab, and then click the Fetch command to pull everything back down.

[image]

In the branches folder you will see all origin branches.

[image]

Now you can right click and choose 'New local branch from' to enter the branch name and track to origin.

[image]